# this while calling async functions with decorators

Tags: typescript

I have file named `commands.js`. In my concept it will be called before actual function is called and will do checks if `message` has `content` and `content` is equal to (or starts like) `cmd`. Everything was OK before I made my function async. I converted file with decorator (according tips from `tsc`) and there's result:

```
import { Message } from "discord.js";

export function command(cmd:string, eq:boolean=false) {
    return (target, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(msg: Message) => Promise<void>>) => {
        let f = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = (msg: Message) => {
            if(!msg.content || msg.content.trim() === "") {
                return Promise.resolve<void>(undefined);
            }
            if(!msg.author) {
                return Promise.resolve<void>(undefined);
            }
            if(eq && msg.content !== cmd) {
                return Promise.resolve<void>(undefined);
            } else if(!eq && !msg.content.startsWith(cmd + " ") && msg.content !== cmd) { 
                return Promise.resolve<void>(undefined);
            }
            if(f) {
                return f.call(f.caller, msg);
            } else {
                return Promise.resolve<void>(undefined);
            }
        };
        return descriptor;
    };
};
```

It works, but in real function (`f`) `this` not persist, so there's no way to get anything from it.

What I'm doing wrong and how to get `this` back in my async function?

```
@command("!ping", true)
async onMessage(msg:Message) {
    msg.react("");
    let startDate = Date.now();
    msg = await msg.channel.sendMessage(":information_source: Pong!");
    let diff = Date.now() - startDate;
    // THAT'S THE POINT WHERE IT CRASHES
    this.log("info", `Ping for sendMessage in Channel#${msg.channel.id}: ${diff}ms`);
    msg.edit(`:information_source: Pong - \`${diff}ms\`!`);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change descriptor to be classic function and then you can access scope directly from `this`. Also if you change descriptor.value to be an async function, you can use await directly in decorator. https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dycwcg

```
descriptor.value = async function(msg: Message) {
  await f.apply(this, msg);
}
```